# RTSP c++ livestream sample source code?

Tags: c++, webcam, live-streaming

i was wondering what is the best way to livestream a camera using RTSP? i have been looking for hours but could not find anything any server source code that allows webcam livestreaming in c++ would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many links to various server RTSP implementations, some open source and free on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol).

Like this open source C++ [one](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/).